# between two tables am getting vertical space like 1px of border in outlook 2013, 2010, and 2007

Tags: html, css, outlook

Between two tables am getting vertical space like 1px of border in outlook 2013, 2010, and 2007.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="700" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fffcf5" style="background-color:red; border:none; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td width="15"><table width="300" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fffcf5" style="background-color:#000000; border:none; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-collapse:collapse;" background="#000000">
        <tr>
          <td width="15" height="170">logo </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="490" height="170px" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fffcf5" style="background-color:#000000; border:none; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-collapse:collapse;" background="#000000">
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <td width="15" height="35px">emptyspace</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="red">
          <td width="15" height="100">heading</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <td width="15" height="35">emptyspace</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Its working fine in chrome and Firefox browsers.

This is the image which am getting error in outlook 2013. Hi sir here am getting some issue in outlook 2013 so am sending screen shot kindly have a look and help me.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You had some oversized widths in your email give this a try...

```html
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
  style="background-color:green; 
    border:none;  
    border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>
  <table width="300" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="orange" 
   style=" border:none;  
     border-collapse:collapse;">
   <tr>
     <td width="15" height="170">logo </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <table width="400" height="170px" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#fffcf5" 
    style="background-color:#000000; 
      border:none;  
      border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <td width="15" height="35px">emptyspace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="red">
      <td width="15" height="100">heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <td width="15" height="35">emptyspace</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</table>
```

in emails you'll need to add style="display:block;" to images for them to remove the padding

Comment: Taken from your lower section of description, you are talking about an image right?

Comment: HI Aaron thanks for your replay. But here am taking about between two tables not inside content. it means when i add two tables inside main table, between two tables am getting space like 1px gap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Aaron thanks for looking my code, here am not getting two tables in single row its splitting row by row please have a look in outlook 2013 and 07,10 in chrome and firefox working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="margin: 0px;"` to all the tables, tr, and td because Outlook automatically adds a 1px margin round the tables if no margin is specified.

You might need to add `padding: 0px;` as well.

This is based on my own trial and error, please comment below if it doesn't work, will try and update my answer.

Comment: Hi Calv T thanks for replaying on my question. But still there is a border 1px problem in outlook 2013, 07,10 between two tables. So please if you get any solution post me thanks in advance.

Comment: HI Calv T thanks for your replay,
Have to check in www.mailchimp.com, here we can send our html file as a mail to your configure mail in your desk. So there we can find the bug. And only in outlook 2013,10,07 only we can find error.

Comment: @RamanaV I ask this because after running your EXACT html you gave in the test I get no white spaces. Are you sure you have no external css that mailchimp inlines?

Comment: Also, your screenshot is different to your code? There is no green in your code...

Comment: Hi Calv T. yeh its little changed.check this code....and still am getting this problem

Comment: @RamanaV why is your table width 390, then your td widths only 15?

Comment: T we can make 100% width no issue but the mail bug am getting the space between two tables in out look.